# Django - Check If form field contains a whitespace

Tags: python, django

In my project, I have a **forms.py** that contains the following field:

`fullName = forms.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=255, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Full Name', 'class': 'fullNameField'}))`

In my views.py, I check  if the field does not contains a whitespace:

```
if not ' ' in form.cleaned_data.get('fullName'):
                    context ['fullNameError'] = "Please enter a valid full name"
```

When I submit the form and add a space, `the context ['fullNameError']` is called when it shouldn't be.

Does anybody know why? Thank you.

Comment: Look at the ordering of the words in your if statement.

Comment: This should be in a form validation method anyway - ie `clean_fullName`

Answer (score 1):

First, what you want to do is:

```
if ' ' not in form.cleaned_data.get('fullName'):
    # stuff goes here
```

Now, to make this cleaner. Form validation must be made inside the form. Check [this part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

Here is how your form should look lile:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # define fields here

    def clean_fullName(self):
        full_name = self.cleaned_data['fullName']
        if ' ' not in full_name:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Cannot contain spaces")

        return full_name
```

This way, the error is attached to the form field and your code is correctly decoupled.

Comment: When I add this code, I get another error when submitting the form regarding the validity of my email field. I know this code has created the problem because before adding it, the invalid email message was never displayed.

Comment: Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Wait I think I got it. In my views.py, I display an error to the user regarding the validity of the email when **form.is_valid()** is false. However I want the **Cannot contain spaces** error to occur instead of this. How do I do this?

Comment: If you have an error related to an email field, this is due to this email field validation, not the fullName field. I don't know how your model fields nor your form field are define. I can't tell you anything more.